# Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 has problems with wifi and bluetooth with RTL8723DE

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, realtek-wireless

I have two laptops (asus and HP), in the ASUS all the tools work correctly the problem is in the HP.

On my HP Laptop 14-cm0xxx laptop, I have problems starting Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

I don't think it's a hardware problem, since everything worked correctly with the Windows operating system before switching to Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried several solutions on the network but without any positive results, I tried to solve the problem by installing ubuntu 19.10 and the same problem follows.

Here are some information about the components of my system:

```
 description: Notebook
 Product: HP Laptop 14-cm0xxx (3PX47LA # ABM)
 Manufacturer: HP
 version: Chassis Version
 Series: 5CG82547RX
 width: 64 bits

 * -network
   description: Ethernet interface
   Product: RTL8111 / 8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

I attach images with the problems

[No wi-fi adapter found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8Mf.png)

[Problems with bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCF0y.png)

[Problems with bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlplQ.png)

[Additional Drivers > No additional drivers avalible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVXgM.png)

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

**Result**

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel modules: rtl8723de 05:00.0
VGA compatible controller [0300]:
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.  [AMD/ATI]
Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15dd] (rev c5)
```

Comment: What result from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: did you try to update the firmware

Comment: mokutil --sb-state
Result: SecureBoot disabled